# Изменение strokeDashoffset строки SVG в цикле for

Tags: javascript, html, css, svg, анимация

Я пытаюсь анимировать расширение линии.

У меня уже есть это решение в `css`, но мне нужно сделать это и в `javaScript`, потому что это единственный способ получить длину пути, которая мне нужна для реализации анимации.
Я думаю, что я очень близко подошёл к решению, но оно не работает! Есть идеи?

Ниже мой код. Как вы можете видеть, я получаю длину пути и присваиваю  `strokeDashArray` значение этой длины.
 Это означает, что линия будет пунктирна, но пунктир заполняет всю строку.

Трюк заключается в уменьшении значения `strokeDashoffset`, потому что это определяет, где начинается тире.
Поэтому, если это также начинается с `pathLength`, линия будет полностью невидимой, и уменьшение значения покажет рисование линии.

```js
var element = document.getElementById("animpath");
var pathLength = element.getTotalLength();

element.style.strokeDasharray = pathLength;
element.style.strokeDashoffset = pathLength;

function animateRoute (e) 
{
e.style.strokeDashoffset = e.style.strokeDashoffset - 100;
}

for (i = 0; i < 100; i++)
{
animateRoute(element);
}
```

<sub>Свободный перевод вопроса [Change strokeDashoffset of a SVG line in a for loop](https://stackoverflow.com/q/28971942/7394871) от участника  [@Kalle Kromann](https://stackoverflow.com/users/4655407/kalle-kromann).</sub>

Прим. переводчика

Я выбрал этот пост для перевода по двум причинам: так как часто встречал вопросы типа,- как с помощью `JS` вычислить длину линии и нарисовать её. Во-вторых мне показался интересен сам прием анимации штриховки с помощью `JS`. Данный прием, на мой взгляд может быть использован в интерактивном веб-дизайне.  Например штриховка чекбоксов, вместо стандартных галочек и т.д.

Comment: Ассоциация: https://stackoverflow.com/q/28971942/7394871

Answer (score 4):

Код:

```
function animateRoute (e) 
{
   e.style.strokeDashoffset = e.style.strokeDashoffset - 100;
}

for (i = 0; i < 100; i++)
{
   animateRoute(element);
}
```

В основном эквивалентен:

```
e.style.strokeDashoffset = e.style.strokeDashoffset - 10000;
```

Потому что цикл пробивает все его итерации, не давая возможности браузеру  обновить страницу.

Чтобы обойти это, сделайте один шаг в цикле, а затем вызовите `setTimeout()`, чтобы  браузер вернулся к нам немного, и чтобы мы могли сделать следующую итерацию.

```js
var element = document.getElementById("animpath");
var pathLength = element.getTotalLength();

element.style.strokeDasharray = pathLength;
element.style.strokeDashoffset = pathLength;

function animateRoute(e, len) 
{
  
  //На каждом шаге мы уменьшаем смещение тире
  len -= 10;
  if (len < 0)
    len = 0;  

  element.style.strokeDashoffset = len;

    //Нам нужно прекратить цикл, когда длина достигнет `0`
  
  if (len > 0) {
    // Сделать еще один шаг
    setTimeout(function() { animateRoute(e, len); }, 10);
  }
}

animateRoute(element, pathLength);
```

```html
<svg viewBox="-10 -10 420 120">
  
    <path id="animpath" d="M 0 0 L 400 10 0 20 400 30 0 40 400 50 0 60 400 70 0 80 400 90 0 100"
          stroke="black" stroke-width="3" fill="none"/>
  
</svg>
```

<sub>Свободный перевод ответа [Change strokeDashoffset of a SVG line in a for loop](https://stackoverflow.com/a/28983680/7394871) от участника  [@Paul LeBeau](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1292848/paul-lebeau).</sub>